# "no matching function for call to..." error, using function as argument

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to call a method, `traverse` from a separate class, `Tree2`. Traverse takes a function as an argument that is defined outside of any class. When I try to call traverse in the `Tree2` constructor, (line 56: `primary.traverse(function, root);`)
I am getting an error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Tree1<int>::traverse(<unresolved overloaded function type>, Node2<int, int>*&)'
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Node1
{
    T *keys;  // An array of keys 
public:
    Node1();
    
    template<typename func, typename Node>
    void traverse(func f, Node *root) {
        f(keys[0], root);        
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Tree1 {
    Node1<T> *root;

public:
    Tree1() : root(new Node1<T>()) {
    }

    template<typename func, typename Node>
    void traverse(func f, Node *root) {
        root->traverse(f, root);
    }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class Node2
{
    U **keys;    
public:
  Node2() {
    keys = new U *[20];
  }

};

template<typename T, typename U>
inline void function(T &k, Node2<T, U> *node) {
    cout << "Called" << endl;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
class Tree2
{
    Node2<T, U> *root;
    Tree1<T> &primary;

public:
    Tree2(Tree1<T> &primary) : primary(primary), root(new Node2<T, U>()) {
        primary.traverse(function, root);        
    }
};

int main() {
    Tree1<int> t;
    Tree2<int, int> i(t);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `addMeIn` is a template. You should read the full error message. It tells you what is wrong

Comment: I think _less_ code to get to the bottom of the problem is the key. Make a [mre].

Comment: indeed. I am certain that there is a solution to your problem, but currently the problem is that the error is hidden in a wall of code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: yes I made a mistake with copy paste before, now I get this: https://godbolt.org/z/MK19W3sdE. Error seems quite clear. Do you understand what it means when it says "...template argument deduction/substitution failed:.... couldn't deduce template parameter 'func'.." ?

Comment: @zfazal10 Just deleting your comments doesn't get us closer to solving the problem. Try what I suggested above. Make a [mre]. If you _can't_ reproduce the problem you're on to something.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I edited the question and replaced the code with the closest thing to a minimal reproducible example I could manage. If you want me to minimize it even more let me know

Comment: @zfazal10  If I take [your code](https://godbolt.org/z/6aWEv8qn9) I would have to "fix" it. Use the compiler to go through the obvious errors. The online compiler I used for your code is really good. It compiles as you type.